# ESP32 ***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task has been detected

Tags: esp32, uart, esp-idf

working with ESP-WROOM-32 on a Lolin board. I also use esp-idf in VS code editor.
I get the error below when I am using UART.

`***ERROR*** A stack overflow in task uart_task has been detected`

I have a uart task with a one-second period. this task reads the uart port 2 into a buffer with size of 256, every one second.
then it looks for some specific pattern at the beginning of the received buffer to parse it by passing the buffer to another class.

here is my uart task code. (*sorry I cant post the complete code*)

```cpp
char uart_recv_data[256] = "";
static void uart_task(void *arg)
{
    uart_config_t uart_config = {
        .baud_rate = 115200,
        .data_bits = UART_DATA_8_BITS,
        .parity    = UART_PARITY_DISABLE,
        .stop_bits = UART_STOP_BITS_1,
        .flow_ctrl = UART_HW_FLOWCTRL_DISABLE,
        .source_clk = UART_SCLK_APB,
    };

    uart_driver_install(2, 256 * 2, 0, 0, NULL, 0);
    uart_param_config(2, &uart_config);
    uart_set_pin(2, 17, 16, -1, -1);

    while (1) {
        uart_read_bytes(2, uart_recv_data, 256, TIMEOUT);
        ESP_LOGI(UART_TAG, "%s", uart_recv_data);

        if(!strncmp(uart_recv_data, "pattern", 7)){
            parse();
        }
        uart_recv_data[0] = '\0';
        vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS);
    }
}
```

here is my function that parses the string using MyClass:

```cpp
void parse(){
    bool ret;
    MyClass myClass = MyClass();
    myClass.parse_string(uart_recv_data);
}
```

`parse_string(char* buffer)` function of `MyClass` simply uses a `sscanf()` functions and extracts some integer out of the input string.

apparently everything works fine until line `vTaskDelay(1000 / portTICK_PERIOD_MS)`

I tried reducing the size of MyClass (commenting some of integer fields of the class) but nothing changed.

Comment: Hi Ida, this is a very common problem - you didn't allocate enough stack when creating the task. `sscanf()` uses a lot of it. See [why "A stack overflow in task iot\_thread has been detected" is coming continuously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970388/why-a-stack-overflow-in-task-iot-thread-has-been-detected-is-coming-continuous)

Comment: Thank you @tarmo ! I doubled my stack size in `xTaskCreate()` and it worked fine. As I found out, using `sscanf()` when we have limited resources is not a standard thing.